# Pull Refresh with Alamofire Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire, get-request

On my app, I am using Alamofire to implement pull to refresh, which is working to refresh but unfortunately doesn't bring back any data. What am I doing wrong? Something for sure I am missing.

Here is the code

my class EarthquakeListing

```
var earthquake: Earthquake?
var refresh = UIRefreshControl()
```

on the `viewDidLoad()`

```
// Refresh Control
    //let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        self.tableView.refreshControl = (self.refresh)
    } else {
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refresh)
    }
```

Alamofire on `viewDidLoad()`

```
Alamofire.request("http://www.seismicportal.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?limit=50&format=json").responseJSON { response in
        //print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url


        if let data = response.data{
            do {

                self.earthquake = try
                    JSONDecoder().decode(Earthquake.self, from: data)
                print("features data: \(String(describing: self.earthquake?.features))")
                // print("data: \(self.features.count)")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.refresh.endRefreshing()
            }
            catch{}
        }
    }
}
```

and the func of objc

```
@objc func refreshData() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    self.refresh.endRefreshing()
}
```

Comment: `refreshData()` doesn't do a new Alamofire request. That's normal then.

Comment: All you are doing is calling `reloadData` on the tableView. Your not actually attempting to load any new data via the API. Make a request using Alamofire and on completion then reload the tableView

Comment: Just add Alamofire.request method in refreshData() function and call in viewDidLoad() also.

Comment: Create 1 method and move API Calling code from `viewDidLoad` to inside this method and call that method in `viewDidLoad` and in `refreshData` method and currently you just reloading tableview.

Comment: Thank you all for the help is working...  I will update the code for someone who might have the same problem

Comment: @KonstantinosMasouras I'd recommend posting an answer instead of updating the question

Answer (score 0):

Add your Alamofire request in a function and call it inside `refreshData()`. And for first time data loading you can call that function(containing Alamofire request) inside your `viewDidLoad()`.

```
func myRequest() {
    // Alamofire request goest here.....

    /* Inside of Alamofire callback block */
       // Assign data to data source
       self.tableView.reloadData()
       if (self?.refresh.isRefreshing)! {
          self.refresh.endRefreshing()
       }
    /*--------*/
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myRequest()
}

@objc func refreshData() {
    myRequest()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update your method with the following code:**

```
@objc func refreshData() {
    // start refresh control
    self.refresh.beginRefreshing()

    // get data from server
    Alamofire.request("http://www.seismicportal.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?limit=50&format=json").responseJSON { response in
        if let data = response.data {
            do {
                self.earthquake = try JSONDecoder().decode(Earthquake.self, from: data)

                // End refreshing and reload table
                self.refresh.endRefreshing()
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            catch{}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP found the solution 6 Min ago.

Comment: we don't need to call `self.refresh.beginRefreshing()` as it is called when user pulls the tableview

Comment: @SubhajitHalder I know. For the first time, this method will be called from viewDidLoad so this will show activity indicator on the table view. This can be helpful if the code is to be triggered programmatically.

Comment: @Kalpesh I understood your point but calling `self.refresh.beginRefreshing()`  programatically does not shows the refresh control, we need to add this line too to show that `tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentOffset.y - (refreshControl.frame.size.height)), animated: true)`, and if we call this inside the `refreshData()` there might be some issues

Comment: @SubhajitHalder, There's no issue if we write this line `self.refresh.beginRefreshing()` at the beginning of API Call and there's no need to set `tableView` `contentOffSet`.